# Callbacks in GUI Design in JavaFX

Tags: user-interface, javafx

I'm trying to design a set of related class in JavaFX.

I have an object of the class Board that creates some objects of the class Box.
Inside the class Box I create some objects of class Button.

When I click a Button, I want the execution of the method trigger of the Box.

Inside the trigger method of the Box, I want that the execution of the method calculation of the Board.

It the calculation method returns  is true, then the button changes its color, othewise the Box that contains the button changes its color.

The first idea I had to implement this is to use some kind of callback passed from the Board to the Box and from the Box to the Button.

Then I had another need: repeat this mechanism for another function (if the button is pressed with the right button, if calculation_shape method of the Board returns true, the button becomes a circle, otherwise the Box becomes a circle).
So I added another set of callbacks.

Anyway this seems to me a code smell, because to add the second feature, I modified all interfaces and all classes.

Is there another way to do it in the realms of the GUI?

Thank you

Here it is the MRE. The behavior is silly, but my questions are:

1) is this the right way to communicate between GUI elements?

2) what if I need to add more communication interfaces between children and parents? I will have very long constructors with lot of interfaces...it seems to me like a code smell...

```java
public interface Triggerable {
    boolean trigger(int size);
}


public class MyButton extends Button {

    Triggerable method;
    int buttonSize;
    String buttonName;

    public MyButton(String name, int size, Triggerable t) {
        super(name);
        buttonName = name;
        this.setMinSize(100, 30);
        this.setOnMouseClicked(e -> MouseClickedAction(e));
        buttonSize = size;
        method = t;
    }

    void MouseClickedAction(MouseEvent e) {
        if(method.trigger(buttonSize) == true ) {
            System.out.println(buttonName + " triggered.");
        }
    }
}

public interface Calculable {
    boolean calculate(int totalSize);
}


public class Box extends VBox {

    String boxName;
    int numberOfButtons = 3;
    int boxSize;
    Calculable method;

    public Box (String name, int size, Calculable m) {
        boxName = name;
        for ( int i = 0; i < numberOfButtons; i++ ) {
            this.getChildren().add(new MyButton("Button" + i  + boxName , i, block -> trigger(block)));
        }
        boxSize = size;
        method = m;

    }

    public boolean trigger(int buttonSize) {
        if(method.calculate(boxSize+buttonSize) == true) {
            System.out.println( boxName + " triggered.");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    }
}

public class Board extends HBox {

    String boardName;
    int numberOfBoxes = 3;
    int boardThreshold = 2;

    public Board (String name) {
        boardName = name;
        for ( int i = 0; i < numberOfBoxes; i++ ) {
            this.getChildren().add(new Box("Box" + i , i, block -> calculate(block) ));
        }
    }

    public boolean calculate(int totalSize) {
        if(totalSize > boardThreshold) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Modified the post to add the minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These subclasses really just seem redundant. Instead of

```
    for ( int i = 0; i < numberOfButtons; i++ ) {
        this.getChildren().add(new MyButton("Button" + i  + boxName , i, block -> trigger(block)));
    }
```

you could just do, e.g.

```
    for (int i = 0 ; i < numberOfButtons ; i++) {
        final int size = i ;
        Button button = new Button("Button" + i + boxName);
        button.setOnAction(e -> trigger(size));
        this.getChildren().add(button);
    }
```

And your trigger method can either receive the button as a parameter, to change its color, or you can create an observable property somewhere, and observe it to change the button's color. In real life your observable property would be part of your data model, but in concept something like:

```
    for (int i = 0 ; i < numberOfButtons ; i++) {
        this.getChildren().add(createButton(i));
    }
```

with

```
private Button createButton(int size) {
    Button button = new Button("Button " + i + boxName);
    BooleanProperty someState = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
    someState.addListener((obs, wasInSomeState, isNowInSomeState) -> {
        if (isNowInSomeState) {
            button.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
        } else {
            button.setStyle("");
        }
    );
    button.setOnAction(e -> someState.set(trigger(size)));
    return button ;
}
```

If you need such buttons more globally, just move that creation method to a factory class, instead of subclassing `Button`.

In general, this just looks over-engineered. Try to 1. avoid excessive inheritance (use aggregation or factory methods for objects where appropriate), and 2. don't replicate standard API (your `Triggerable` and `Calculable` interfaces are just replicates of [`IntPredicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/IntPredicate.html), and even then your example doesn't really demonstrate a need for using that at all).

Comment: First thing: thank you very much for your help, I got your point.
With the usage of the observables I can better realize my behavior.

The other point was: how can I observe from a creator class (Box) a property of a created class (Button).
So you suggest me to use a factory.
My goal is that the higher level of the hiearchy need to observe some properties of the created objects.
Why do you prefer a factory method instead of subclassing?

Comment: @Pich Your subclasses seem to exist only for the purpose of setting properties (including listeners and observers) to specific values. Subclasses should typically add or specialize behavior, imho. That's an opinion and my preferred style, and others might disagree, but my general recommendations are to subclass judiciously.

Comment: Ok, thank you.
Just another question to go deep with the problem of observable of the created class needed by the creator class: the proper way is using the factory?

Comment: @Pich that's hard to answer definitively without knowing more details of the project. I always follow some kind of MVC design, so there is always an observable data model. Then anywhere I'm going to be creating any kind of view, the model is available and I can just register listeners with it to make sure the view is in sync with the model. If I needed to create the same view components from different parts of the application, I'd consider a factory to do that, but that's only likely to happen in a pretty large-scale application.